# SI-model How to find the eigenvalues,solve numerical the system and Plot the answer

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have this system. I have found the equilibrium points and the Jacobian Matrix of each point. Now I am trying to calculate the eigenvalues and in the second step solve numerical the system.

```
r = 1; b = 1; c = 1/100; \[Mu] = 4/10;
f = r*x[t] - b*x[t]^2 - c*x[t]*y[t] - 1*x[t]*y[t]/(a + x[t]);
g = -\[Mu]*y[t] + 1*x[t]*y[t]/(a + x[t]);
deq1 = x'[t] == f
deq2 = y'[t] == g
equilibrio = Solve[{f == 0, g == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}]
MatrixForm[jacobian = D[{f, g}, {{x[t], y[t]}}] // Simplify]
A=Simplify[MatrixForm[jacobian] /. equilibrio]
```

Due to Helpful Answers: Thanks for the responses. Turns out the easiest answer for me to solve the numerical system is

```
soln = ParametricNDSolveValue[{deq1, deq2, x[0] == 0.2, 
   y[0] == 0.05}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 200}, {a}]
```

Here is where I faced the problem

```
A = jacobian /. equilibrio
eigen = EigenValues[A]
Plot[Evaluate[{soln[1][t],soln[2][t]}], {t, 0, 200}]
```

Could you help me, please?

Comment: There are multiple problems. (1) Get rid of `MatrixForm`. It cannot be used inside computations. (2) Correctly spell `Eigenvalues`. (3) `NDSolveValue` cannot handle a non-numeric system. This system has a parameter `a`. Possibly you will want to use `ParametricNDSolveValue`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you for the advice to use ```ParametricNDSolveValue```  .Although I tried to find the ``` Simplify[jacobian /. equilibrio]``` and ```Eigenvalues```  but it does not work too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not define "a", I arbitrarily set it to 1. Then take care about using "MatrixForm". This is a wrapper used only for display, not calculations.

```
a = 1; r = 1; b = 1; c = 1/100; \[Mu] = 4/10;
f = r*x[t] - b*x[t]^2 - c*x[t]*y[t] - 1*x[t]*y[t]/(a + x[t]);
g = -\[Mu]*y[t] + 1*x[t]*y[t]/(a + x[t]);
deq1 = x'[t] == f;
deq2 = y'[t] == g;
equilibrio = Solve[{f == 0, g == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}]
```

[image]

As you can see, there are 3 solutions. In the following, for simplicity,  I only use the first one.

```
MatrixForm[jacobian = D[{f, g}, {{x[t], y[t]}}] // Simplify]
MatrixForm[A = Simplify[jacobian /. equilibrio[[1]]]]
```

[image]

[image]

With this we can get the eigen values and solve the ODE:

```
eigen = Eigenvalues[A]

soln[t_] = 
 NDSolveValue[{deq1, deq2, x[0] == 0.2, y[0] == 0.05}, {x[t], 
   y[t]}, {t, 0, 200}];
Plot[soln[t], {t, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The parameter "a" is not given by the problem

Comment: "a" appears in f and g. You can not use NDSolveValue (or any function: N...) if you have undetermined parameters.

Comment: So I have to define the parameter and then I could solve it. Right? Is there any other solution?

Comment: You could try to find an analytic solution using "Solve" or "SolveValue". But it is not sure that an analytic solution exists, in this case the numeric solution is the only way.

Comment: That was really helpful. Thank you!